# how to display the number of products in that category? in laravel using Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, count

How can I display the number of `products` in a `category` using Eloquent ORM?

##### `Categories` table

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('categoryName');
    $table->text('categoryDescription')->nullable();
    $table->integer('parentId')->nullable();
    $table->string('categorySlug')->unique();
    $table->text('categoryImage');
    $table->tinyInteger('status');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

##### `Products` table

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->text('productName');
    $table->text('productDescription')->nullable();
    $table->integer('categoryId');
    $table->integer('manufacture')->nullable();
    $table->text('productTags')->nullable();
    $table->text('productSlug');
    $table->float('regularPrice');
    $table->tinyInteger('status');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want, for example:

1. Fruits & Vegetables (5)
2. Fresh Fruits (2)
3. Breakfast (3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the `products` relationship in your `Category` model:

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Product::class, 'categoryId');
}
```

You can then do something like:

```php
$categories = \App\Models\Category::query()->withCount('products')->get();

// each $category in your collection will have a products_count attribute

foreach($categories as $category){
   dump($category->id.' has '.$category->products_count.' products!');
}
```

*This will not be recursive. If you need recursion, you'll have to so some researches since it is way more complex to implement without performance issues.*